How do I get my github action to run on pull requests in to a certain branch AND when deployment status is == success?
I want my test script to run on pull requests going into the main branch but only when deployment_status is == success as the test script hits all the url's on staging so need to build on vercel to be complete e.g.: successfully deployed.
With my current yml workflow what happens is the first on condition is skipped and then once deployment is sucessful second on condition will run so it shows one test skipped and one test run - but ideally I just want the one test ran on succesful deployment (only when PR's are going into main) - I am using dev as target branch atm for testing.
How do I achieve this? here is my yml code:
name: Site URL test

run-name: Running sitewide check before merge

on:
  pull_request: 
    branches:
      #This will be master branch when finished
      - dev
  deployment_status:


jobs: 
  test-urls:

    if:
      github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4  
        with:
          node-version: '21.5.0'  

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: www

      - name: Run sitewide URL check 
        run: npm run test-sitemap
        working-directory: www


A suggestion could be to create an environment and use the wait timers feature. The job would be triggered just by the pull_request clause, wait for a fixed enough time, and finally verify the deployment status.

Issue is there could be a queue of deployments on vercel so a wait timer would never be accurate
